# Multi Threading File Saving operation?

Tags: c++, multithreading, file

I am developing an application which basically stores 2D matrices in memory and performs mathematical operations on them. When I benchmarked my software I found that file reading and file saving were performing very badly. So I multi threaded file reading and this resulted in tremendous boost in performance. The reason for boost in this performance may not be due to I/O but rather due to the translation of `string` data from file into `double` being distributed among threads.

Now I want to improve my file saving performance. Simply speaking it is not possible to multi thread saving data to a single file. So what if the data is broken up into different files (= number of cores)? Is this the correct way to solve this problem? Also how do I make all these files look as a single file in Windows Explorer so as to hide this complexity from the user?

Comment: How big are your files and matrices? Does write time really matters that much? (Often, computation takes more time than I/O on big matrices).

Comment: Why do you have strings? Can't you just save the doubles as doubles, in a binary file?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the software basically solves Linear Equations, so if the user is solving for say 1000 equations then there is (1000000 * 8bytes = 8MB) in memory. To transfer this to a File currently it is taking about 1.8 sec which I feel is bad on my 5400rpm Laptop. File reading takes 0.4 secs while solving the equations takes only 0.8 secs. So you see the File saving is the worst performing operation. Now this is only for 1000 equations, for say 15000 equations (max possible on 32 bit) the time is unbelievable.

Comment: @doctorlove the strings are there so that the file saved by my application is compatible with MS Excel.

Comment: Your program is strange or your operating system is slow: on my Linux/Debian/Sid/x86-64 system (i3770K, GCC 4.8 with `gcc -O2`), a tiny C program looping a million times `for (long i=0; i<cnt; i++) printf("%.5f\n", log(1.0+i*sqrt((double)i)));` takes (when redirecting stdout to `/tmp/my.out`) `0.44s user 0.01s system 91% cpu 0.492 total` .... The output contains a million numbers, totalizing 8999214 bytes....

Comment: You should show your exact code doing the output.

Comment: Your code prints the number with only 5 digit precision while my program prints with 15 digit precision, hence your equivalent time should be 0.44*3 = 1.32 secs, anything wrong here?

Comment: In my answer, I updated the precision to 15 digits, and the time is not 3 times slower!

Comment: Why is it not possible to trivially serialize the writing? The only hindrance is that unless you are willing to add leading zeroes (ugly...) so the output is fixed size, you don't know the end size in advance. You can partition those matrices into, say, 4 pieces and "write" out the string data to 4 buffers (each owned by one thread), and have the main thread block on a barrier. Then you know the exact size of each output block, which you can write in one go. On the other hand, you _could_ add leading zeroes and simply have threads write to a memory mapped file, leave the rest to the OS.

Comment: @Damon thanks for pitching in. Honestly your comment is too technical for me to understand, can you please simplify what you said? "Why is it not possible to trivially serialize the writing?", "You can partition those matrices into, say, 4 pieces and "write" out the string data to 4 buffers", "have the main thread block on a barrier", "simply have threads write to a memory mapped file, leave the rest to the OS". Sorry for being a bozo but please can you simplify these lines so that I can understand?

Comment: Well, one value in a matrix is independent of another, so you can print one number in one thread, and another number in another one. So if you use two threads, you can for example have one thread do the first half, and the other one the second half. That way, your double-to-string conversion is done at twice the speed. The only problem is, it all needs to be in one file at the end. If you use zero-padding (like 00000.32435) so every output number is the same size, you know the exact size of the output of 1/2 your matrix.

Comment: Writing to a file that way is not very efficient, but luckily you can memory map files. This effectively turns a file's contents into a region of memory. What you write to the memory will land inside the file on the disk. So what you could relatively easily do is create a file of the known size, map it, and have several threads fill in the data. Mapping a file that can hold around a million values, is no big challenge to a modern operating system. The nice thing is that the _actual_ writing happens "magically" without you doing anything.

Comment: I had implemented a similar functionality using QString (my project is in Qt) earlier which was very fast than the current, but I was forced to remove it, why? Because when you store these many strings in memory the size becomes so large that it overflows the 2GB limit on 32 bit. But then after reading from http://jovislab.com/blog/?p=76 I think QString is the memory hog. So I will now store std::string in memory and test with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize my comments:

- generally, matrix computations is much slower than matrix printing.
- on my Linux/Debian/Sid/x86-64 system (i3770K, GCC 4.8 with `gcc -O2`), a tiny C program looping a million times `for (long i=0; i<cnt; i++) printf("%.15f\n", log(1.0+i*sqrt((double)i)));` takes (when redirecting stdout to `/tmp/my.out`) `0.79s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 0.810 total` .... The output contains a million numbers, totalizing 18999214 bytes.... ; so you might blame your file system, operating system, or library (perhaps using C `<stdio.h>` functions like `printf` might be a bit faster than C++ `operator <<` ....).
- you could [serialize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) your output in some binary format if you really wanted to, and provide e.g. a `.dll` plugin for Excel to read it; but I don't think it is worth your effort.

<sup>Notice that I updated my sample code to output 15 digits per double-precision number!</sup>

BTW, I suggest you to make your [sequalator](http://sequalator.blogspot.fr/) software a [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), e.g. to publish its source code (e.g. under [GPLv3+](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) license) on some repository like [github](http://github.com/).... You probably could get more help if you published your source code (under a friendly free software license).

You might consider switching to Linux (and use a recent GCC, e.g. 4.8); it probably is faster for such applications (but then, I agree that using Excel could be an issue; they are several free software altenatives, e.g. [gnumeric](https://projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/); also [scilab](http://www.scilab.org/) could interest you ...)

<sup>BTW, nothing in my answer above refers to multi-threading, because you cannot easily multi-thread the output of some textual file....</sup>

Comment: a little off topic, I saw your website and I understand that you are a very senior level programmer. I am just a beginner. What is your short review of my software? I am scared to release the source code because the software might not be so good from the average programmers perspective.

Comment: I am not able to (and not at all interested in) "reviewing" a software whose source code is not visible to me. Don't be afraid of showing your code.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link for Serialisation. It helped me clear a lot of my doubts. And it is ok if you find it it uninteresting to "review" my software. I did not mean a detail review, sorry if you got it wrong.

Comment: My point is that for me a software is most importantly a source code: analyzing binary code (i.e. [decompiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler) it) is beyond my abilities and my interests (I actually believe it is an [intractable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intractability_(complexity)) problem, perhaps even an [undecidable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) one ...). If you don't show us your source code, we cannot review your software!

Comment: Its fine, I never asked decompiling. Just wanted some of your insights after using the software. Did not mean to review from a software developer's perspective, just from a users perspective. Since it is my first time that is why. But it is ok maybe my communication was not so good...

Comment: I strongly believe you should show your software in source form and publish its source code with some free software license. I cannot be a potential user of your software: I am a Linux only user (never used Windows) and I am a free software zealot.

Answer (score 1):

> The reason for boost in this performance may not be due to I/O but
>   rather due to the translation of string data from file into double
>   being distributed among threads.

If this is the case, consider storing binary data instead of text.  Given that you are dealing with 2D matrixes, a useful format might be [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/).  You can then read and write at full speed, and it supports compression too if you need that for even more disk space savings.  I doubt you'll need threads at all if you do this.

Comment: I am storing the data in the form of text so that the file is compatible with MS Excel. If the data is stored in binary format, Excel would not understand it.

Comment: You could write a separate utility to convert the binary output to Excel format, or write some `.dll` for Excel to read it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch so you mean that binary should be the default file format for my application and there can be another option to export data to text format? Maybe you can summarise all your comments into one nice answer which I can mark as correct answer?